# Nodejs server crash when res.send() large string

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous, xmlhttprequest

I am new to JS and NodeJs. my Nodejs application crashes when I make a get request and it tried to return me a large string

app.mjs

```
app.get('/log', function (req, res) {
 ....
  function callback(data) {
    res.status(200).json({ data })
  }
  logEndPoint = 'https://getmylogs/log'
  deviceHandler.getLog(logEndPoint, callback); <--- get data from another API endpoint then return it using `res` as callback funcction
}
)
```

here is the `getLog()` function

```
function getLog(url, callback, method='GET') {
  var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
  http.open(method, url, false);
  ...
  http.onload = function() {
    if (http.status != 200) {
      callback(`Error ${http.status}: ${http.statusText}`);
    } else { // show the result
      // callback(http.responseText); <--- this crash the app
      // callback('something short works derp');
      console.log("sending the status back")
      callback(Buffer.byteLength(http.responseText, "utf-8")); <----- print 1323196 bytes so 1.3 MB but sometimes it can be up to 5MB
      return;
    }
  };
  http.send();
}
```

any idea why?

basically I would start my application with  `node --experimental-modules app.mjs` in one terminal and in the other terminal I would run `curl -G  'http://localhost:7000/log?param=param`

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can we see what's the error message for the crash?

Comment: yep I updated the code and some snippet

Comment: i think its the VS Code Crash, do you print/log the response to terminal ?

Answer (score -1):

It appears that the size of the string exceeds vscode's heap memory configuration. I'd suggest running VSCode using the following command to increase the maximum memory:

```
code --max-memory=12288mb
```